# Does anyone still use MvcContrib in .NET MVC3 projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-3

Aside from T4MVC, does anyone use MvcContrib for MVC3 projects? We've decided to incorporate a prototype project that was built in MVC2 last year. It mainly uses the paging and sorting namespaces from MvcContrib, but also some fluent html helpers.

We want to upgrade the project to MVC3 and I am wondering if we should also try to remove some of the MvcContrib dependencies. Reasons to keep? Reasons to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I use it in my projects. I use the [Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) and the [TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) extensively.

Answer (score 1):

I am using TestHelper also, very useful and well written!

Answer (score 0):

MvcContrib's strongly typed RedirectToAction gives you compile time errors if you delete or rename an action that you redirect to. With normal redirects, you're stuck with magic strings for action names, and as such the risk of overlooking a breaking change in your application.

The ModelStateToTempData attribute is also helpful as it lets you retain modelstate while you redirect from a update POST action back to the form page instead of returning a view directly from the update action (which is a bad practice).